# jQuery Animating dropdown css menu ul display:block issue

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to add simple animation to css menu 
http://jsfiddle.net/BGV2Z/2/

The issue seems to be display:block; . If you hover first time menu works fine , on mouseleave the menu that disappeared appears again in far left position or in top position( depending on level ) .

```
    $("li").on('mouseenter', function () {

        $(this).find('ul').first().css('display', 'none').fadeIn(500, function () {

            $(this).css('display', 'block');

        });

    }).on('mouseleave', function () {

        $(this).find('ul').first().fadeOut(500, function () {

            $(this).css('display', 'none');

        });
    });
```

I am missing something obvious any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `position: relative;` to your CSS for `ul.dropdown li`

```
ul.dropdown li {
    float: left;
    min-height: 1px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin:0 5px;
    display:block;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Nice find ! Than you!

Answer (score 1):

You could do it without the need of jQuery and use CSS3 animations :)

Just add some `transition` animations, an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/xine/BGV2Z/13/

Comment: Nice one also , but I need bit more animations and also supporting browsers without css3 support. But thank you for the example